# How to resolve errors with Event IDs 6482 and 6398 in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-search, logs, setspn

In my event log I see this error generating every minute (Event ID 6482):

> *Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance
>   (e1df40b4-a364-47af-a4fa-69e010bf3893). Reason: A call to SSPI failed,
>   see inner exception. Technical Support Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to
>   SSPI failed, see inner exception. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI
>   failed, see inner exception. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is
>   incorrect    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[]
>   message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential
>   credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel
>   requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel
>   allowedImpersonationLevel)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream
>   stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream
>   stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream
>   stream)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator
>   upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder
>   decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper&
>   timeoutHelper)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection
>   connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection
>   connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean
>   isAdministrationServiceJob)*
>
> Also Event 6398 shows up every now and then :
>
> *The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CustomDictionaryDeploymentJobDefinition
>   (ID ec00dacf-a390-48ff-a800-05f9678bf768) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below. Failed to run flow
>   Microsoft.CustomDictionaryDeployment. Correlation Id:
>   ed8f429d-8e96-509c-0eb5-1627b4f98499.*

I have been trying to resolve these for the last couple of days. But nothing helped.

Just to let you know, I tried adding/resetting the SPN from PowerShell as Administrator using setspn but it says "Insufficient Access Rights to perform this operation" although ideally it should since I am using the privileged account to run this script. Moreover I dont access to have Domain Controller so can not delegate the access rights either.

Please let me know how to resolve this as these 2 errors are filling up my event logs and might be causing the site to go down quite often.

Answer (score 3):

clearly, it is SPN issue. You have to make sure the SPN properly created.Could you please run the setspn and get list of all SPN which already created.

> if you need to allow delegated administrators to configure service
>   principal names (SPNs), you must ensure that their user accounts have
>   the Validated write to service principle name permission. More
>   information, please refer to the link:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241.aspx

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/9deb1d13-088a-421b-b926-2f9034795e01/sharepoint-2013-error-admin-component-is-not-up-and-running?forum=sharepointsearch)

Another thing: 
please check the service accounts of SharePoint Timer Service and SharePoint Search Host Controller service, add a SPN entry for each the service account as the following command:

Setspn.exe -A HTTP/

After the above, do an IISREST.

Comment: Thank you Waqas Sarwar. Well, if I run setspn -L <account> I see:

Comment: Thank you @Waqas . Well, if I run setspn -L <account> I see - Registered ServiceName for Cn=**** and so on DC=com: <blank> . So now when I try to run setspn -A or setspn -S in order to register the SPN to a host it says I dont have necessary permission. But I am running the script as an administrator. Also I can't delegate the access as I dont have the option to use the domain controller. So looks like I myself will have to add the SPN, is there any alternative way to do that? Or how can i resolve this permission issue because I am already using the administrator account?

Comment: if you are using the kerberos, you have to create the SPN properly. On the AD server, do you have other administrator who can runt he setspn for you.

Comment: if you check the technet, they have information how to delegate the permission